# Selecting correct study design and statistical analysis for my project

Tags: logistic, observational-study, case-control-study, medicine, research-design

I am analyzing risk factors associated with surgical site infections where we want to have a 3:1 case-control study.  Other than some brief lectures in my classes, the only thing we were taught about matching is that it is used to adjust for confounding, so I am not familiar on how to actually perform matching and if that changes the logistic regression I would run? The risk of SSI from literature is 2 - 6% per 30-40 million surgeries, I don't have access to my dataset yet, but the percent of cases would be similar.

However, my preceptor said an option is to design the study as a prospective cohort and that I can choose between case-control or the cohort, but I wanted some advise on which seems to fit this analysis best. SSI(yes/no) is the outcome and I want to analyze various risk factors that are already known from literature, such as: age, length of surgery, temperature during surgery, glucose control(yes/no), correct antibiotic(yes/no), etc.

Comment: It sounds like it boils down to an analysis of EHR no matter the design. Matching from an already collected dataset doesn't make sense, it's just throwing observations away. Case control designs save costs when assessing the exposure is expensive.

Comment: Can you please explain SSI?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen SSI is a surgical site infection that can occur after a surgical procedure where the patient develops an infection in the site where the surgery was performed.